# Macbook Gestures 3-finger drag

Tags: macbook-pro

How do I add the apple gestures such as three finger drag? I have tried fusuma but they do not input how to add 3-finger drag only how to add gestures that activate commands when the gestures are used.

The 3-finger drag is useful for a lot of my programming needs so it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I am a mac user as well, but what 3-finger drag are you talking about? Do you mean dragging up with 3 fingers to show all open windows, or do you mean something else?